# Django how to make flexible generic views

Tags: django, django-views, dry, django-class-based-views

How do you make flexible generic views?

At the moment I have two models one for apples and one for pears, and a single template I want to use.

```
from django.views import generic

class AppleIndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'fruit/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'apple_list'

   def get_queryset(self):
     return Apple.objects.values()

class PearIndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'fruit/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'pear_list'

   def get_queryset(self):
     return Pear.objects.values()
```

Is there a way of being more DRY? There should be a better way.

Thank you for your time

**EDIT ADDITIONAL REQUEST**

Can someone write out this example out as a unified view, could it's unbound to one model. So I can see it as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only need to provide model or queryset, if you follow the principals you won't need to provide template_name or context_object_name, in the list template you can access to context_object name as:

```
 modelname_list
```

or just

```
object_list
```

if you don't provide.
Create templates in your

```
app_dir/templates/app_dir/<model_name>_list.html
```

and you won't need anything else.

Comment: Would I need to have two templates one each Apple and pear? Sorry I think I misunderstand. How would you unify the two indexviews or will I still need two, just more simplified?